# underlying connection was closed using webclient from azure

Tags: winforms, c#-2.0

I am windows application developer currently am working in a tutorial based application.my application is built in framework 2.0,c#.net ,i have a task that i need to download zip files from azure cloud storage, i know i can simply done this using windows azure nuget package in higher framework but the problem is i can't upgrade the application framework i need to done the task with this framework. can anyone please help me how to solve this, i got a small hint and i tried on that time i got an error "underlying connection was closed". please help me
my code

> ```
>  string spath = Application.StartupPath.ToString();
>             string lPath = spath + "\\EncryptedFiles";
>             string dTo = Path.Combine(lPath, File);
>             if (System.IO.File.Exists(dTo))
>             {
>                 System.IO.File.Delete(dTo);
>             }
>             NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("*****", "*****");
>             CredentialCache cCache = new CredentialCache();
>             cCache.Add(new Uri(fileName), "Basic", credential);
> ```

```
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });

            WebClient wClient = new WebClient();
            wClient.Credentials = cCache;
            wClient.DownloadFile(fileName, dTo);
```

Comment: This problem occurs when the server or another network device unexpectedly closes an existing TCP connection. This problem may occur when a time-out value on the server or on the network device is set too low. Did you try this [Resolution](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/826210)?

Comment: can you please explain it how can i do it